Flutter tests fail if executed all together
Test Cases
This is the screen_layout_test.dart file that has couple of test cases:

void main() {
  late MockFirebaseCrashlytics firebaseCrashlyticsMock;
  late MockFirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfigMock;

  setUp(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    firebaseCrashlyticsMock = MockFirebaseCrashlytics();
    firebaseRemoteConfigMock = MockFirebaseRemoteConfig();
    Crashlytics.firebaseCrashlytics = firebaseCrashlyticsMock;
    RemoteConfigFirebase.firebaseRemoteConfig = firebaseRemoteConfigMock;

    await setUpTestHive();
    await Hive.openBox('app');
    await Hive.openBox('secureBox');
    await Hive.openBox('temporary_base_url');
  });

  tearDown(() async {
    await tearDownTestHive();
  });

  testWidgets(
    ' screen_layout renders header when showHeader = true: ',
    (WidgetTester tester) async => await tester.setupInitConfigs(
      (tester) async {
        const _headerMock = 'HEADER_MOCK';

        final body = ScreenLayout(
          showHeader: true,
          header: Text(_headerMock),
        );

        await tester.createRootWidgetAndPump(body: body);
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();
        expect(find.text(_headerMock), findsOneWidget);
      },
    ),
  );

  testWidgets(
    ' screen_layout login modal when isLoggedIn = true in auth state: ',
    (WidgetTester tester) async => await tester.setupInitConfigs(
      (tester) async {
        MockAuthRepository()..isLoggedIn = true;

        final body = ScreenLayout();
        await tester.createRootWidgetAndPump(body: body);
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();

        // Tap the user icon
        await tester.tap(find.byIcon(AntIcons.userOutlined));
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();

        // Verify the login modal is displayed
        expect(find.byType(DSMLoginModal), findsOneWidget);
      },
    ),
  );

  testWidgets(
    ' screen_layout showBackButton = false should hide back button: ',
    (WidgetTester tester) async => await tester.setupInitConfigs(
      (tester) async {
        final body = ScreenLayout(showBackButton: false);
        await tester.createRootWidgetAndPump(body: body);
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();

        // Tap the user icon
        expect(find.byIcon(AntIcons.arrowLeftOutlined), findsNothing);
      },
    ),
  );

  testWidgets(
    ' screen_layout renders title widget when param is passed: ',
    (WidgetTester tester) async => await tester.setupInitConfigs(
      (tester) async {
        const _mockTitleText = 'TITLE_MOCK';
        final body = ScreenLayout(
          title: Text(_mockTitleText),
        );
        await tester.createRootWidgetAndPump(body: body);
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();

        // Tap the user icon
        expect(find.text(_mockTitleText), findsOneWidget);
      },
    ),
  );

  testWidgets(
    ' screen_layout renders trailing widget when passed: ',
    (WidgetTester tester) async => await tester.setupInitConfigs(
      (tester) async {
        const _mockTrailing = Icon(Icons.home);
        final body = ScreenLayout(
          trailing: _mockTrailing,
        );
        await tester.createRootWidgetAndPump(body: body);
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();

        // Tap the user icon
        expect(find.byIcon(Icons.home), findsOneWidget);
      },
    ),
  );
}

Extension being used

extension WidgetTestExtensions on WidgetTester {
  Future<MultiProvider> createRootWidgetAndPump({
    required Widget body,
    AppProvider? appProvider,
    AuthExpireState? authExpireState,
    ACLCubit? aclCubit,
    AuthCubit? authCubit,
    DSMProvider? dsmProvider,
    V5SearchQueryReq? query,
    V5FlightCubit? v5FlightCubit,
    BookingCubit? bookingCubit,
    FlightSearchTimerState? flightSearchTimerState,
    V5SelectedFLightsState? selectedFlights,
    AddOnProviderState? addOnProvider,
    Map<String, WidgetBuilder> routes = const <String, WidgetBuilder>{},
  }) async {
    final observers = <NavigatorObserver>[];

    final root = MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => aclCubit ?? ACLCubit()
            ..emit(
              ACLState(
                acl: ACLFetchState(),
                fetchGeoLocation: ACLGeoLocationState(),
                fetchOriginAirport: ACLOriginAirportState(),
              ),
            ),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => v5FlightCubit ?? V5FlightCubit()
            ..emit(
              V5FlightState(
                rules: V5FlightFareRules(),
                search: V5FlightSearchState(),
                calenderFare: V5FlightFareCalenderState(),
                query: query,
              ),
            ),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => bookingCubit ?? BookingCubit()
            ..emit(
              BookingState(
                initiate: BookingInitiateState(),
                initiateV4: BookingInitiateV4State(),
                // can add more default states if needed
              ),
            ),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => authCubit ?? AuthCubit()
            ..emit(
              AuthState(
                  // can add default data in states if needed
                  ),
            ),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => authExpireState ?? AuthExpireState(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => appProvider ?? AppProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => selectedFlights ?? V5SelectedFLightsState(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => dsmProvider ?? DSMProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => flightSearchTimerState ?? FlightSearchTimerState(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => addOnProvider ?? AddOnProviderState(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorObservers: observers,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        locale: appProvider?.activeLocale,
        supportedLocales: AppProvider.locales,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          CountryLocalizations.delegate
        ],
        localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
          for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
            if (locale != null &&
                supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
                supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
              return supportedLocale;
            }
          }
          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
        home: Scaffold(body: body),
        routes: routes,
      ),
    );
    await pumpWidget(root);
    return root;
  }

  Future<void> setupInitConfigs(
    WidgetTestBody body, {
    Size physicalSize = defaultPhoneSize,
    double devicePixelRatio = defaultDevicePixelRatio,
  }) async {
    await this.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp());
    final context = this.element(find.byType(MaterialApp));

    /// Needed throughout our app, hence mocking the
    /// context here for each test as a common function here
    App.init(context);

    // Satisfy Flutter Flavors
    AppFlavor.init(PackageInfo(
      appName: 'appName',
      packageName: 'appNamePackage',
      version: '0.7.5',
      buildNumber: '100',
    ));
    await body(this);
  }


Widget Code
And below is the widget code (LENGHTY) but for the sake of reference:
class ScreenLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showBackButton;
  final VoidCallback? onBackPressed;
  final Future<bool> Function()? onWillPopScope;
  final Widget? title;
  final Widget? trailing;
  final bool showHeader;

  final Widget? header;
  final Widget? extendedHeader;
  final Widget? body;
  final Widget? footer;

  final Widget? bottomNavigationBar;
  final Widget? floatingActionButton;
  final Color? scaffoldBackgroundColor;
  final bool showFooter;
  final bool fromSearch;
  final List<Widget>? overlayBuilders;

  final EdgeInsets padding;
  const ScreenLayout(
      {Key? key,
      this.header,
      this.overlayBuilders,
      this.title,
      this.showHeader = true,
      this.showFooter = false,
      this.fromSearch = false,
      this.body = const SizedBox(),
      this.footer,
      this.showBackButton = true,
      this.onBackPressed,
      this.onWillPopScope,
      this.trailing,
      this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
      this.bottomNavigationBar,
      this.floatingActionButton,
      this.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      this.extendedHeader})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    App.init(context);
    final roles = AuthCubit.cubit(context, true).state.data?.data?.role;
    final isPartnerRole =
        roles != null && roles.contains(SastaWalletStatics.partner);
    final isLoggedIn = AuthCubit.cubit(context, true).repository.isLoggedIn;
    final state = DSMProvider.state(context);
    final dsmProvider = DSMProvider.state(context, true);

    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: AppTheme.c.gray1,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light, // for IOS
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // for Android
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
        floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
        backgroundColor: scaffoldBackgroundColor ?? AppTheme.c.scaffold,
        appBar: Platform.isIOS
            ? PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
                child: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: AppTheme.c.gray1,
                  elevation: 0,
                ),
              )
            : null,
        body: SafeArea(
          top: true,
          bottom: false,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  if (showHeader)
                    header ??
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: AppTheme.c.gray1,
                          ),
                          height: 50,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              if (showBackButton)
                                IconButton(
                                  iconSize: 24,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  onPressed: onBackPressed ??
                                      () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    AntIcons.arrowLeftOutlined,
                                    color: AppTheme.c.blue6,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              if (title == null) Space.x1!,
                              title ??
                                  CustomPaint(
                                    painter: HeaderLogoPainter(),
                                    size: Size(112, 20),
                                  ),
                              if (trailing != null) ...[
                                Space.xm,
                                trailing!,
                              ] else ...[
                                Space.xm,
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        await showModalBottomSheet(
                                          context: context,
                                          backgroundColor:
                                              Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                          isDismissible: false,
                                          enableDrag: false,
                                          isScrollControlled: true,
                                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                            maxHeight: 350,
                                          ),
                                          builder: (_) {
                                            return DSMPriceCurrencyModal();
                                          },
                                        );
                                      },
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          SvgPicture.asset(
                                              dsmProvider.getPriceFlag(),
                                              height: 12),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 4,
                                          ),
                                          ClipOval(
                                            child: Text(
                                              "${dsmProvider.getPriceCurrency()}",
                                              style: V3AppText1.l1!
                                                  .cl(AppTheme.c.blue6),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 4,
                                          ),
                                          Icon(
                                            AntIcons.downOutlined,
                                            size: 12,
                                            color: AppTheme.c.blue6,
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Space.xf(0.8),
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                                          context,
                                          DSMAppRoutes.support,
                                        );
                                      },
                                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                          StaticAssets.customerService,
                                          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                              AppTheme.c.blue6!,
                                              BlendMode.srcIn)),
                                    ),
                                    if (!this.fromSearch) ...[
                                      Space.xf(0.8),
                                      GestureDetector(
                                        onTapDown:
                                            (TapDownDetails details) async {
                                          if (isLoggedIn) {
                                            final RenderBox renderBox =
                                                context.findRenderObject()
                                                    as RenderBox;
                                            final Offset offset =
                                                renderBox.localToGlobal(
                                                    details.globalPosition);

                                            showMenu(
                                              context: context,
                                              position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
                                                  offset.dx,
                                                  offset.dy,
                                                  0.0,
                                                  0.0),
                                              items: <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                                                if (isPartnerRole)
                                                  PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                                    enabled: false,
                                                    child: STTag(
                                                      fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                                      label: 'Partner',
                                                      rounded: false,
                                                      filled: true,
                                                      labelColor:
                                                          AppTheme.c.orange9,
                                                      borderColor:
                                                          AppTheme.c.orange3,
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                          AppTheme.c.orange1,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                                  value: 'Option 1',
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'Cancel Booking',
                                                    style: V3AppText1.l1,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                                  value: 'Option 2',
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'Edit Profile',
                                                    style: V3AppText1.l1,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                                  value: 'Option 3',
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'Logout',
                                                    style: V3AppText1.l1!
                                                        .cl(AppTheme.c.blue6),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ).then((String? selectedValue) {
                                              if (selectedValue != null) {
                                                switch (selectedValue) {
                                                  case 'Option 1':
                                                    BookingAddOnsProvider.state(
                                                            context)
                                                        .resetSelection();
                                                    BookingAddOnsProvider.state(
                                                            context)
                                                        .resetSelectionAfterPostBooking();
                                                    BookingAddOnsProvider.state(
                                                            context)
                                                        .reset();
                                                    BookingCubit.cubit(context)
                                                        .reset();
                                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                                        .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                                      AppRoutes.bookings,
                                                      (Route<dynamic> route) =>
                                                          false,
                                                    );
                                                    break;
                                                  case 'Option 2':
                                                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                                                      context,
                                                      DSMAppRoutes.editAccount,
                                                    );
                                                    break;
                                                  case 'Option 3':
                                                    Analytics.logItemClicked(
                                                      AnalyticsScreens.ACCOUNT,
                                                      AnalyticsItems.LOGOUT,
                                                    );

                                                    final isFromEditProfile =
                                                        NavigationHistoryObserver()
                                                            .history
                                                            .any((route) =>
                                                                route.settings
                                                                    .name ==
                                                                DSMAppRoutes
                                                                    .editAccount);

                                                    if (isFromEditProfile) {
                                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                                    }
                                                    AuthCubit.cubit(context)
                                                        .logOut();
                                                    break;
                                                  default:
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                              }
                                            });
                                          } else {
                                            await showModalBottomSheet(
                                              context: context,
                                              backgroundColor:
                                                  Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                              isDismissible: false,
                                              enableDrag: false,
                                              isScrollControlled: true,
                                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                                  maxHeight: 410),
                                              builder: (_) {
                                                return ListenableProvider.value(
                                                  value: state,
                                                  builder: (context, child) {
                                                    return Padding(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          bottom: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                  context)
                                                              .viewInsets
                                                              .bottom),
                                                      child: DSMLoginModal(),
                                                    );
                                                  },
                                                );
                                              },
                                            );
                                          }
                                        },
                                        child: Icon(
                                          AntIcons.userOutlined,
                                          color: AppTheme.c.blue6,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                    Space.xf(0.8),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ]
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                  if (extendedHeader != null) extendedHeader!,
                  if (body != null)
                    Expanded(
                      child: body!,
                    ),
                ],
              ),
              if (showFooter && footer == null)
                Footer()
              else
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: AppDimensions.normalize(25).toDouble(),
                    decoration: UIProps.boxCard,
                    child: footer,
                  ),
                ),
              ...(this.overlayBuilders ?? []),
              AuthExpireUI(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And for some reason, if I execute one by one, they work fine but fails if I execute all together from main()

Are you sure the Hive is restored to the same pristine state before the next test is run? I had some problems with data from previous tests spilling over to the next test case

Can you please describe this a little, I'm not every expert in writing tests just getting started with it @Ber

You should check setUpTestHive() and tearDownTestHive(). They need to ensure that the Hive is clean and empty for each new test. At least that was the problem I once had.
Also, it might help to add the actual messages from a failed test.

Hi @Ber sorry, was away. In my case, the Hive is only storying the baseUrls, or theme configs stuff in it. Does it matter if that's cleared or not? if yest, do In need to delete the HiveBox after every testWidgets ends? Apologies for asking stupid questions. THANKS

In my case the tests depended on the state (contents) of the Hive, so I had to create a new Hive from empty data in each setup. Also, by nature access to the Hive may be concurrent from tests running in parallel, so you may need to make sure this does not happen.
